# Spring MVC AbstractView Java configuration

Tags: java, excel, spring-mvc, pdf, pdf-generation

I am trying to implement Excel/PDF download using org.springframework.web.servlet.view.document.**AbstractXlsxView**.

My application is configured using org.springframework.web.servlet.support.**AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer**.

I have created my *AbstractXlsxView* with ***@Component*** and specified name to it.

```
@Component(VIEW_NAME_BASE_XLSX)
public class BaseXlsxView extends AbstractXlsxView {

public static final String VIEW_NAME_BASE_XLSX = "baseXlsxView";
public static final String MODEL_ATTRIBUTE_NAME_BASE_XLSX_VIEW_BEAN = "MODEL_ATTRIBUTE_NAME_BASE_XLSX_VIEW_BEAN";

@Override
protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> modelMap, Workbook workbook, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Base Sheet");

    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0, CellType.STRING);
    cell.setCellValue(new Date());

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename=" + "BaseExcelDocument" + System.currentTimeMillis());

}

}
```

I am using the specified name as view name in **ModelAndView** returned by my controller.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/exportBaseXlsx")
public ModelAndView exportBaseXlsx(ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    return new ModelAndView(BaseXlsxView.VIEW_NAME_BASE_XLSX, BaseXlsxView.MODEL_ATTRIBUTE_NAME_BASE_XLSX_VIEW_BEAN,
            null);
}
```

This always throws **404**.
It is trying to read a JSP file(as I have configured View resolver) instead of reading *BaseXlsxView*.

[image]

I have seen this way of implementing(not using ***views.xml*** with `<bean id="myBeanId" class="myClassQualifiedName" >`) **AbstractView** is working in other applications but it is not working here.

Comment: please share your configuration

Comment: there is no configuration implemented for `AbstractXlsxView`

Answer (score 0):

I remember that SpringMVC has default view-adapter if you don`t assign , and maybe the default view-adapter returns jsp view.